# error in compiling project having annotations in maven2

Tags: java, maven, annotations, maven-2, maven-compiler-plugin

I am using maven to compile some java classes. One of the classes has an annotation(`@Override`) so when i run `mvn compile` then I get error:

```
 annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
        @Override

 annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
        @Override
```

Although the java version in my system is jdk 1.6.29 still i can't understand this error.
So i there a way by which i can check the jdk version maven is using and perhaps change it.
Or, is there any other solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instruct the maven build to set the compiler flags for compilation of java source level 1.5. This is done inside your `pom.xml` file, adding configuration for the `maven-compiler-plugin` plugin.

For instance:

```
<plugins>
[...]
     <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>default-compile</id>
                  <configuration>
                       <source>1.5</source>
                       <target>1.5</target>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
              </executions>
     </plugin>
[...]
</plugins>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ..does this 1.5 stand for jdk version? Also can i do the same in the global settngs.xml file?

Comment: Yes and no; setting _source_ tag to 1.5 makes maven compiler plugin pass the _-source 5_ argument to javac invocation; similarly _target_ tag is for passing the _-target_ argument. That is for setting the java source code level, I mean, a jdk 1.6 can support all levels among 3, 5 and 6.